# Why is $\omega_1^2$ not semi-basic for $\pi : ASO(3) \rightarrow M \subset \mathbb{E}^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

In *Cartan for Beginners*, problem 2.4.3, the problem is that if $M$ is flat, show that there exist coordinates $x_1,x_2$ and an orthonormal adapted frame $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ such that $\omega_1=dx_1, \omega_2=dx_2$.

My problem is with the hint given, which says that $\omega_1^2$ can be written as $du$ for some function $u:\mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which I understand for a $M$ flat, and then it says, "Since $\omega_1^2$ is not semi-basic for the projection to $M$....

I'm trying to do this book self-study and I just can't figure out how they got that statement, or whether it's related to $M$ being flat, or is something I was supposed to have picked up previously about the connection forms.

Could somebody please explain it?

Comment: this might be of some help, if not now, latter on... http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191088/beginners-guide-to-cartan-for-beginners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is universally true of connection forms. As you change frame (move along the fiber), the transformation law has a $a^{-1}da$ term, which is vertical. I assume you can now use $u$ to find the appropriate frame (all locally)?

Comment: I think so.  The rest of the hint is since du is not semi-basic, there is a vertical vector such that $du(X)$ isn't zero, and therefore u is not constant in the vertical part of the bundle.  Then that means we can find another lift $F$ for which $F*(u)$ is constant. I think that comes from both the transformation law you cited, and the same rotation ($L_a$?) that moves $II$ to a Darboux frame.  Once it's constant, then $d\omega_i = \omega_j^i \wedge \omega_j$ are zero, and $\omega_i = dx_i$ for some  $x_i$.  I am still thinking about your comment, it's a big upgrade for my intuition.

Comment: Sorry, that should be $F^*$